# Wanted: C# hash algorithm that returns UInt16?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, hash

I'm in need for a hash algorithm that takes a string and returns a number that can be stored in a [`UInt16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16(v=vs.110).aspx). I need it for calculating a small checksum number.

Does .Net have an algorithm for this?

Comment: Whats wrong with all of those that return an `int` or whatever, and convert it to `UInt32`?

Comment: Just take *just about any checksum algorithm* and pick 2 bytes you like from the output...? sure, you'll lose entropy, but that is unavoidable for a small checksum

Comment: @YoryeNathan, yeah, you are right. I need a UInt16!

Comment: Just take the `UInt32` and turn it into a `UInt16` in some fashion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [crc16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). [Here](http://www.sanity-free.org/134/standard_crc_16_in_csharp.html) is an example that works with a `byte[]` as input, maybe you can modify it to work on characters instead.



*Added some code for the next person:*

Usage: `ushort hash = Crc16.ComputeHash("Hello World!");`

```
using System;

/// <summary>
/// Creates a checksum as a ushort / UInt16.
/// </summary>
public class Crc16
{
    const ushort polynomial = 0xA001;
    ushort[] table = new ushort[256];

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Crc16"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Crc16()
    {
        ushort value;
        ushort temp;
        for (ushort i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i)
        {
            value = 0;
            temp = i;
            for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                }
                else
                {
                    value >>= 1;
                }
                temp >>= 1;
            }
            table[i] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes the hash.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The input.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ushort ComputeHash(string input)
    {
        if(input == null)
        {
            input = "";
        }

        Crc16 crc = new Crc16();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        return crc.ComputeChecksum(bytes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes the checksum.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes">The bytes.</param>
    /// <returns>The checkum.</returns>
    public ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
            crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ table[index]);
        }
        return crc;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes the checksum bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes">The bytes.</param>
    /// <returns>The checksum.</returns>
    public byte[] ComputeChecksumBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = ComputeChecksum(bytes);
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! That looks like what I'm looking for. I'll try and convert the answer to take a string.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll bite:

```
int hash = "hello".GetHashCode();
ushort hash16 = (ushort) ((hash >> 16) ^ hash);
```

Of course you can also write your own hash if you really want to, but this seems convenient enough.

Comment: On MSDN I read: 'You should never persist or use a hash code outside the application domain in which it was created, because the same object may hash across application domains, processes, and platforms.' 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If it is a requirement of your problem that the hash needs to be persistable, please put that in your question! That's an important restriction.

Answer (score 1):

> Does .Net have an algorithm for this?

**No.**

See [hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) to see what you're looking for. Understand the differences, and choose the one that suits your needs, your post is very "short", and I can't say much. In any circumstances, I don't suggest you to take an output of 32-bit algorithm, and just take the lower 16 bits, this is bad choice.

Are you looking for CRC checksum, are you looking for normal checksum?

Either way, pick your choice, google for `C# <the implementation name>`, and modify it as it suits you.